# How to get the height of pdf?

Tags: pdf, iframe, height, object-tag

How can I get the height of PDF document preferably using javascript, jquery?

OR

How can I adjust the height of iframe to match the height of pdf document loaded inside ?

Comment: You are aware that each page of a PDF may have different dimensions?

Comment: yes, I'm aware of it.